# Text Resize but with defined font sizes?

Tags: 7, theming

I am using the [Text Resize](https://www.drupal.org/project/text_resize) module to dynamically change the font size of my page content. However, instead of having two buttons which increases and decreases font size, I need, instead, to have three buttons so when the user clicks on one, the font size will be set to a preset value. This value should be able to be changed by the client themselves.

Is there a module which is similar to Text Resize but with defined font sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Text Size](https://www.drupal.org/project/textsize)**. It provides 3 buttons and also has settings for increment/decrement step.

step 1: go to admin/config
step 2: User interface -> Text Resize click
step 3: tick Add Reset Button then save